# How to measure nextjs response time components

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, azure-application-insights

I have `next.js` app. There is a simple `SSR` page which has a single database call using `getServerSideProps`. I have also integrated application insights to measure app performance. For this page I see the following timings:

[image]

Database dependency is taking only `4 ms`, but full requests takes much more. I know that it's hard to guess or explain where the remaining time goes, because it depends on code base and what libraries I am using and so on, but maybe there are some techniques which could help me to determine components of remaining request time? I tried to look into [Performance measurement](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/measuring-performance) on official docks, but I think it measures slightly different thing that I want to know.

Comment: Not sure if you've solved this yet, but there is an ongoing discussion on the Next Github. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12382